# can anyone run eclipse galileo on mac os 10.5.8

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am having a serious pain trying to run eclipse in mac os x 10.5.8. I tried every version carbon, cocoa, 32, 64 bit but nothing works i keep getting

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

... or ...

> An internal error occurred during: "Launching TestFooBasicTest". Could not initialize class com.ibm.icu.impl.JavaTimeZone error.

... when I try to run the main class.

I know there's another thread in stack overflow but there's no proper answer if someone fixed it.

Please let me know if someone fixed it

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "other thread" you're referring to? Are you having problems running eclipse or running your own code in Eclipse? Eclipse works fine for me on 10.5.8.

Comment: Could you provide the complete stacktrace for the NoClassDefFoundError. It works fine on my machine and I Carbon 64 bit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553343/cannot-run-debug-java-applications-in-eclipse-javatimezone-issue this is the other thread. I  am having a problem running the code actually.

Answer (score 1):

ICU developer here. Can you save this code as 'tztest.java' and then run "javac tztest.java ; java tztest"

```
public class tztest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] availableIds = java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
        System.out.println("Length: "+availableIds.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < availableIds.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("ID #"+i+": "+availableIds[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't paste the whole output (may be several hundred lines).. but are there any NULL strings?

Comment: I got this exception, for some reason availableIds is coming as null.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.getZoneIDs(ZoneInfoFile.java:729)
        at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getAvailableIDs(ZoneInfo.java:517)
        at java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(TimeZone.java:497)
        at com.yahoo.labs.TzTest.main(TzTest.java:10)

Comment: Hmm.. http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6529213

Can you look for the file ZoneInfoMappings ?

find /System/Library /Library -name ZoneInfoMappings -ls

Comment: Hi Steve, 
It doesn't find that class!!

Comment: You should have the file somewhere on your disk.. like /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/###/Home/lib/zi/ZoneInfoMappings  ( where ### is some version ) .. it might be in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks otherwise .

Comment: Did you ever run a 'time zone updater'? Can you do "java -version" to see which java is being used?  If you run java (not javac) with sudo, does it work?  (sudo java tztest)

Comment: java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04-248-9M3125)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.3-b01-101, mixed mode)

i haven't run time zone updater. Also even if i run with sudo i get the same null pointer because of null availableIds

Comment: ok.. i will try that, lets see but it didn't work for me yesterday. i will give another shot. Thanks

Comment: Actually, even better is NOT to edit the jar at all, but to edit eclipse.ini to add a line at the end (one line, remove the quotes!)

 "-Dcom.ibm.icu.util.TimeZone.DefaultTimeZoneType=ICU"



It's inside Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini

My colleague points out that editing the jar makes it unsigned.

see:

http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/running_eclipse.htm