# Unable to run Java Applications in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot run/debug Java applications in Eclipse (JavaTimeZone issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553343/cannot-run-debug-java-applications-in-eclipse-javatimezone-issue)

Eclipse has failed something big time.

When I try to run a Java Application, I get this:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching (app name)".
org/eclipse/jdt/debug/core/JDIDebugModel
```

An attempt to debug yields this:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching (app name)".
com/sun/jdi/connect/IllegalConnectorArgumentsException
```

Opening the Run Configurations, I get this:

```
Exception occurred creating launch configuration tabs

Reason:
Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui was unable to load class
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.LocalJavaApplicationTabGroup
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui (322).
```

Going to any Run Configuration for a Java Application also gives an error message:

```
No tabs defined for launch configuration type Java Application
```

I am unable to run any Java Applications. I can remove them from Run Configurations, but that's all. Trying to run an app from e.g. the package explorer does nothing. I can still run Android Applications, for example.

I've got Indigo Service Release 2, Java EE IDE version on Ubuntu 12.04/Gnome 3.4.2.1.

Is there any way to fix this? Should I just reinstall Eclipse, maybe some older version?

btw: the error messages are the same as
[Cannot run/debug Java applications in Eclipse (JavaTimeZone issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1553343/cannot-run-debug-java-applications-in-eclipse-javatimezone-issue)
but I don't have GPE installed and it's Java Applications, not Web Applications that are failing.

Comment: What is your system-default jdk?

Comment: "jdk1.7.0_04", should be Oracle Java 7

Comment: Thank you for your good question - I tried switching to Open JDK 1.7.0_07 and things are working now. The Oracle JDK is probably not the source of the problem though, because it hasn't been updated since Eclipse was working the day before yesterday.

Comment: I met the same issue on ubuntu 12.04.1. The final solution is,

Reinstalling tzdata-java was the fix for me:

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Kane! It works for me! :> Ubuntu 12.04.1, Eclipse 4.2, OpenJDK 1.7.0_07.